# Pythonic way to handle long-running CLI commands with subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, subprocess, azure-cli

What is the most pythonic syntax for getting `subprocess` to successfully manage the running of the following CLI command, which can take a long time to complete?

**CLI Command:**

The CLI command that `subprocess` must run is:

```
az resource invoke-action --resource-group someRG --resource-type  Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates -n somename78686786976 --action Run
```

The CLI command runs for a long time, for example 11 minutes in this case, but possibly longer at other times.

While run from the terminal manually, the terminal prints the following while the command is waiting to hear back that it has succeeded:

```
\ Running
```

The `\` spins around while the command runs when the command is manually typed in the terminal.

The response that is eventually given back when the command finally succeeds is the following JSON:

```
{
  "endTime": "2022-06-23T02:54:02.6811671Z",
  "name": "long-alpha-numerica-string-id",
  "startTime": "2022-06-23T02:43:39.2933333Z",
  "status": "Succeeded"
}
```

**CURRENT PYTHON CODE:**

The current python code we are using to run the above command from within a python program is as follows:

```
def getJsonResponse(self, cmd,counter=0):
  process = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
  data = process.stdout
  err = process.stderr
  logString = "data string is: " + data
  print(logString)
  logString = "err is: " + str(err)
  print(logString)
  logString = "process.returncode is: " + str(process.returncode)
  print(logString)
  if process.returncode == 0:
    print(str(data))
    return data
  else:
    if counter < 11:
      counter +=1 
      logString = "Attempt "+str(counter)+ " out of 10. "
      print(logString)
      import time
      time.sleep(30)
      data = self.getShellJsonResponse(cmd,counter)
      return data
    else: 
        logString = "Error: " + str(err)
        print(logString)
        logString = "Error: Return Code is: " + str(process.returncode)
        print(logString)
        logString = "ERROR: Failed to return Json response.  Halting the program so that you can debug the cause of the problem."
        quit(logString)
        sys.exit(1)
```

**CURRENT PROBLEM:**

The problem we are getting with the above is that our current python code above reports a `process.returncode` of 1 and then recursively continues to call the python function again and again while the CLI command is running instead of simply reporting that the CLI command is still running.

And our current recursive approach does not take into account what is actually happening since the CLI command was first called, and instead just blindly repeats up to 10 times for up to 5 minutes, when the actual process might take 10 to 20 minutes to complete.

What is the most pythonic way to rewrite the above code in order to gracefully report that the CLI command is running for however long it takes to complete, and then return the JSON given above when the
command finally completes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my code is pythoic, but I think it's better to run it in Popen.
I can't test the CLI command you should execute, so I replaced it with the netstat command, which takes a long time to respond.

```
import subprocess
import time


def getJsonResponse(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        encoding='utf-8',
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    while(True):
        returncode = process.poll()
        if returncode is None:
            # You describe what is going on.
            # You can describe the process every time the time elapses as needed.
            # print("running process")
            time.sleep(0.01)
            data = process.stdout
            if data:
                # If there is any response, describe it here.
                # You need to use readline () or readlines () properly, depending on how the process responds.
                msg_line = data.readline()
                print(msg_line)
            err = process.stderr
            if err:
                # If there is any error response, describe it here.
                msg_line = err.readline()
                print(msg_line)
        else:
            print(returncode)
            break

    # Describes the processing after the process ends.
    print("terminate process")


getJsonResponse(cmd=['netstat', '-a'])
```

Comment: When we paste our command from the OP into the `cmd` variable in your code, the response we get is `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.  We left everything else besides the value of `cmd` the same in your code.  What must be changed to resolve this error?

Comment: [https://bugs.python.org/issue17023](https://bugs.python.org/issue17023)

Comment: Can't you solve the problem by adding a shell = True argument to the Popen method?

Comment: Or what about a statement like this?
cmd = ['az','resource','invoke-action','--resource-group','someRG','--resource-type','Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates','-n', 'somename78686786976','--action','Run']